# Kubernetes Ingress Controller Redirect if contains characters like "?"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an ingress controller working for UI container service and backend container service. my ingress configuration is as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: testapp
 annotations:
  rules:
  - host: test1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /static
        backend:
          serviceName: ui-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /apicall
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Which is working fine. Now I need to forward this ingress URL if it contains `?`.

For eg, if url is `test1.example.com/?productid=10001` I need to add static before this `?` and forward it to `test1.example.com/static?productid=10001`.

Is this behavior possible through below annotations?

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

If yes, how to have that regex kind of url where if `?` is present in the url followed by any string/characters, add `static` keyword before it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at the YAML below to understand how works [rewrite rule](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by  `(.*)`  will be assigned to the placeholder  `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the  `rewrite-target`  annotation.
>
> For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:
>
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/new`

In your case, you will need to follow a similar procedure. But first, I suggest you do a separate ingress for each path. This will help you keep order later and additionally you will have an independent ingress for each path. Look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1065154/nginx-ingress-rewrite-rule/1065176#1065176) to see why and how you should create a separate ingress.

> Now I need to forward this ingress URL if it contains ?. for eg if URL is test1.example.com/?productid=10001 i need to add static before this ? and forward it to test1.example.com/static?productid=10001.

You will need to create an appropriate capture group. For the data you presented it will look like this:

```yaml
 - path: /(/|$)(.*)
```

and the annotation should be like this:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /static/$2
```

In this case, everything that gets captured from the URL after the `/` character will be rewritten to the new address, which will look like `/static` and the address that was before. There should be no problem with the question mark.

If you need to create a regex that will act on a question mark, you will need to prefix it with a `\` character, which is described [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special).

Also, consider that you are currently targeting root `/` path and want to create 2 ingresses. I also suggest creating appropriate endpoints depending on the situation, so that you can easily create 2 different ingresses responsible for directing different traffic.